# Reversing the min and max values in column chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have chart of winning positions. http://jsfiddle.net/DhcTV/4/ like this. As you can see the last ones and the biggest postion get's your attention.

How to reverse the columns so the smallest positions get the biggest columns and the last positions gets small column ?

Would this be possible to do with the highcharts or does this requires additional calculation ?

Comment: can you make your question more clear? please? what do you mean by "How to reverse the columns so the smallest positions get the biggest columns and the last positions gets small column ?"

Comment: If possible, try changing Y-axis values. Start from 350 instead of 0.

Comment: @ParthThakkar well i want to reverse the result columns, the values should be same. (I dont mean the yAxis property reveresed: true)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just reverse the order of the values? See your code [updated](http://jsfiddle.net/DhcTV/6/).
In order to reverse the values of an array, you can use the [reverse(..)](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_reverse.asp) function on the values array.